# Microsoft ADAL acquireTokenSilentSync fails

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, adal

The token generated by the ADAL is having an expiry of 1 hour. To create the token the app is calling the ADAL method acquireToken. When reopening the app or engaging with the app which was in background/idle for more than 1 hour, the token has to be refreshed. This refresh should happen in the background without user consent. For this, the app is calling the ADAL method acquireTokenSilentSync. This function is throwing an exception an ADAL exception AuthenticationException. Due to this, the app has to be force-closed so that the token will be created again once reopening. Logs are below

```
Token cache item contains empty refresh token, cannot continue refresh token request ver:3.0.2 Android 28 null
  Microsoft.ADAL.request_id: 34533-b84f-45ae-a4f5-29e7h6789d02
  Microsoft.ADAL.api_error_code: AUTH_REFRESH_FAILED_PROMPT_NOT_ALLOWED
  Microsoft.ADAL.is_frt: false
  Microsoft.ADAL.device_id: lSZf/vWb4AcUTIgbKXDVlQ7jYmBGmLPEMLwHYQao3C4=
  Microsoft.ADAL.cache_event_count: 3
  [2020-05-14 05:11:21 - 344267-f177-48f8-ad39-ec085udh240c] AUTH_REFRESH_FAILED_PROMPT_NOT_ALLOWED:Prompt is not allowed and failed to get token. No result returned from acquireTokenSilent ver:3.0.2 Android 28 null
```

Answer (score 0):

The acquireTokenSilentSync function will first look at the cache and automatically checks for the token expiration. Additionally, if no suitable access token is found in the cache, but refresh token is available, the function will use the refresh token automatically. This method will not show UI for the user. If prompt is needed, the method will return an exception. The Error prompt you are receiving says the Token cache is empty, make sure token is available in the Cache